# Laravel datatable relations error print

Tags: laravel, datatable, eloquent

> Problem is how to print(show) Topic's name in View. and i tried this topic->topic_name still got error.

**Model of Vote**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'topic_id' ,'question', 'answer', 'lastname', 'firstname', 'identity', 'user_id',
];
public function topic(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic');
}
```

**Model of Topic**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'topic_name',
];
public function votes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
}
```

**APIController@getColumnSearchData**

```
$customers = Vote::select(['id', 'topic_id', 'question', 'answer','lastname','firstname','identity', 'user_id', 'created_at']);
return Datatables::of($customers)->make(true);
```

**View**

```
processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{{ route('api.column_search') }}',
    columns: [
      { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
      { data: 'topic_name', name: 'topic_name' },    there is error
      ... ...,
    ],
```

Comment: I haven't used that package before but I'd try changing `Vote::select(` to `Vote::with('topic')->select(` and change `data: 'topic_name', name: 'topic_name' },` to `data: 'topic', name: 'topic.topic_name' },`

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. Sorry didn't work.

Comment: No problem. I thought that would have worked, I think the answer you need is on this page: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

// controller file:

```
$customers = Vote::with('topic')->get();
return Datatables::of($customers)->make(true);
```

//view:

```
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
ajax: '{{ route('api.column_search') }}',
columns: [
  { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
  { data: 'topic.topic_name', name: 'topic.topic_name' },    there is error
  ... ...,
],
```